# Changed image of UIImageView from code, not centered anymore

Tags: iphone, objective-c

So I just spent like one hour Googling for some answers.

1. I added UIImageView with Interface Builder and I set image to some existing image.
2. I wanted to make the image centered, so I changed mode to centered. Worked.
3. Now I wanted to change the image from code. So I set image in IB to nothing and I did `imageView.image = (UIImage instance)`

Now the image changed, but it's not centered anymore.

Also, here's an interesting thing: I tried also not changing image in IB, I just left it set to some image and then I changed image from code. I could see both images! The one set in IB was centered (like I want it) and the new one was overlaying on the left.

Any ideas please?

Also I probably lack some basic knowledge of this View stuff, can anyone please point me at documentation where this is explained?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it! Thanks James Huddleston for useful comments.

You were right. There must have been to UIImageViews.

Here's what happened. I actually used viewWithTag: to find that view (it wasn't linked directly - it was in a UITableViewCell). Well, it apparently didn't work with 0, when I changed tag to 1 - it worked.

Comment: I'm glad you got it working. The default tag value for views is 0 and `viewWithTag:` also considers the receiver to be part of the search. So if you call `[aView viewWithTag:kTag]` and the tag value for `aView` is `kTag`, `aView` might be returned. Consequently, it's best to avoid using 0 for tag values.

Comment: Yep, here's what probably happened. When I called viewWithTag on my UITableViewCell it probably returned self - and I think I changed its image property.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have two overlapping `UIImageView` subviews. One of them is referenced by `imageView` in your view controller and doesn't center. The other isn't referenced by your view controller but does center. The solution would be to get rid of the non-referenced image view.

Comment: I don't think so. I just set up UIImageView in IB and I linked it to an instance variable imageView. No way another instance could be created. When? How?

Comment: You could verify this by changing the View Mode in IB to column view and looking for an extra `UIImageView` subview. Off the top of my head, I can't think of a way for a single `UIImageView` to show two images simultaneously. The strangeness with the centering vs. left align also indicates that there are two views with two different content modes.